# Is a cross domain canonical appropriate when an API is used to pull in data from a page on another site?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical

This is simply a question to figure out if I am understanding this and my approach is correct.

- `www.ticketwebsite.example/event/event-name` - Event ticket website
- `www.mysite.example/event/event-name-123` - Custom website.

The contents of both URLs are the same. I want to tell Google the source of the content on `mysite.example` is from `ticketwebsite.example`

I have `mysite.example`.  It pulls through the event ticket data from www.ticketwebsite.com API.

Is it correct that the canonical to be used on `www.mysite.example/event/event-name-123` is: `www.ticketwebsite.example/event/event-name`?

The text on the two pages (including the title), the images and the CTAs are all the same.

Answer (score -1):

No. Canonical URLS are used to indicate that two seperate pages have in fact the same content. Your custom `www.examplesite.com/event/event-name-123` does not have the same content as `www.ticketwebsite.com/event/event-name`, merely the same data. This also implies the pages are part of the same domain.

If your custom site simply pulls data and displays them in its own format, alongside other data not present in the `ticketwebsite` then the usage of canonical url is incorrect.

Comment: My custom site does indeed simply pull data and displays it in its own format etc. Is there something else similar to canonical that I should be looking at maybe then? I am trying to pass all SEO 'points' to the original source website/page (ticketwebsite.com).

Comment: You can use canonical to pass ranking to the other page, but you should have your page match the other page exactly. Text/images/videos would need to be identical between the two sites. If you need to boost the source site you do not need a canonical url pointing to it. Simply add a link pointing to the source site and tell you got your info from there.

Comment: If the pages have all the same data and the same text, I'd think a cross domain canonical would be just fine.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the degree to which the content between the two pages should be the same is so much we could practically speak of the same page. We have zero information from op if the "contents are the same" refers to an aggregated version of the information of really, 100% the same,

Comment: Text (incl Title), Images and CTA's are all the same.

Comment: If the percentage similarity is above 90% and the main content (data) are the same id go for a canonical tag.